# Using variables in exec.Command Golang

Tags: go, freeswitch

I am trying to use variables within the string

i have tried the following to no avail :(

```
astatus, _ := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "fs_cli -x\"callcenter_config agent get status\"", agent_uuid).Output()
```

```
astatus, _ := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "fs_cli -x\"callcenter_config agent get status\"" + agent_uuid).Output()
```

it does not seem to be parsing the output of the variable agent_uuid

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is `agent_uuid` supposed to be a new argument to `fs_cli` or a continuation of `get status`? Because if it's the latter you should use `+`.

Comment: i did use + in my example doesnt work

Comment: You have to run built executable under some debugger such as `strace` and see how the executable you want to run is run.

Comment: change `Output()` to `.CombinedOutput()` and see what error it returns.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide an example of a correct command line invocation, and I'm not familiar with `fs_cli`.  But I think your issues here is a quesiton of whitespace for the shell command.

```
astatus, _ := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "fs_cli -x\"callcenter_config agent get status\"", agent_uuid).Output()
```

That's going to produce a shell invocation such as:

```
/bin/sh -c" "fs_cli -x\"callcenter_config agent get status\"" agent_uuid
```

Because that's how you did the spaces.  but looking at the `fs_cli` data online, it should probably be something more like:

```
"/bin/sh", "-c", "fs_cli -x \"callcenter_config agent get status agent_uuid\""
```

Actually there's really no purpose in using a shell command.  You aren't using any bash features - it's just a passthrough to executing another program.  So instead of formatting for shell, just invoke the program directly.  Then, each argument will be a separate string, and you won't have to worry about whitespace:

```
astatus, err := exec.Command(
   "fs_cli",
   "-x",
   fmt.Sprintf("callcenter_config agent get status %s", agent_uuid),
).Output()
```

If you can't get this working, please make sure to edit the question with the exact invocation of `fs_cli` that you use at command line, with the whitespace in the correct place.  Then it will be an easy matter to fix the invocation here.

```
astatus, _ := exec.Command(...)
```

Don't ever ignore errors in Go.  Remember it doesn't raise exceptions - checking error status is generally the only way to detect runtime errors.  You're hurting your own debugging by ignoring the error that might come from the command invocation.